# WinJS listview error in Cordova

Tags: winjs, visual-studio-cordova

Adding the following to a cordova index.html results in:

"Unable to get property 'firstElementChild' of undefined or null reference"

when WinJS.UI.processAll() is executed?

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" >
</div>
```

Other WinJS control types seem to work but not this.  Anyone seen this or know what to do about it?

Comment: A ListView typically needs more options to instantiate, such as a layout. Have you tried more complete code from http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview?

Comment: I was having the same issue and got around it by calling WinJS.UI.processAll() before attempting to bind data.  Now I' m having another issue, Unable to get property classList for undefined or null reference.